# Maven JavaEE application with separated frontend and backend

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee

I would like to create a Java EE application with fully separated `FrontEnd` and `BackEnd`. I found some tutorials where these two modules were packaged into one EAR file. I could create this, and I could deploy my application to the application server.

For security reasons now I have to separately deploy the FrontEnd (Tomcat) and the BackEnd (Weblogic).

What do I have:

**Front:**

1. JSF pages
2. ManagedBeans

**Back:**

1. Sessionbeans with business logic (EJB)
2. Entity classes.

The communication interface between these two layers would be `RMI` calls.

The first solution when I had one EAR project with these two modules were working, because my backEnd module pom.xml packaging was `jar`:

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

Thus I could include this built `jar` to my frontEnd's classpath, and my frontEnd saw the required classes.

Now I tried to create ear from my backEnd because with `jar` packaging I cannot inculde required libraries to my backend and they're missing in runtime. So i changed backEnd packaging to `ear` in my `pom.xml` Ok, but if I have `EAR` build from backEnd then i cannot include it to my frontEnd classpath and my frontend cannot see required classes from the backEnd.

I'm sorry i'm totally confused about this. Can you give me any advice or a tutorial about what is the proper way to separate these two modules. For example how is it possible to build an `EAR` and a `JAR` at the same time with `maven`?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your project you should have a module with the EJBs and the according packaging type "ejb". Normally an "ejb-client" artefact is also generated. This can be used as a dependency for the frontend.
The frontend should be packaged as a "war", the backend as an "ear".

Have a look at the respective maven plugins (EAR, WAR, EJB):

- https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/
- https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/
- https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ejb-plugin/

Comment: Thank you, but what should be in my EAR project if I have all my entity classes and ejb classes in the EJB plugin? And can I build dependencies into my EJB project? what is going to be the output? I have to deploy EAR to weblogic and WAR to tomcat. please help me. Thank you!

Comment: Excuse my late answer.

Comment: In the simplest case your EAR contains just the one EJB. And yes, you can use dependencies. They are normally packaged inside the EAR. The EAR encapsulates your code and all of its dependencies.
Normally the EARs are seperated from each other, so that you can use different versions of a library in different EARs.

Answer (score 2):

Try this it may help your question..
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/skinny-wars.html

In a typical J2EE environment, a WAR is packaged within an EAR for deployment. The WAR can contain all its dependent JARs in WEB-INF/lib but then the EAR can quickly grow very large if there are multiple WARs, due to the presence of duplicate JARs. Instead the J2EE specification allows WARs to reference external JARs packaged within the EAR via the Class-Path setting in their MANIFEST.MF.

Answer (score 1):

If your front end is in JSF create a separate maven project that will have all UI related code ( css/js/*.jsf and Backing Bean)  e.g DemoProject-UI will be your front end project name.Write all your UI related things in this project.

Now your JSF page backing bean need to comunicate with with service layer. For this purpose create a seprate maven project e.g DemoProject-Service.You can write a Webservice inside this project that will be access by DemoProject-UI through proxy. DemoProject-Service will have one web service that will be called and it will have backend logic using Spring service / DAO etc.

From your question its asked that you want both on seprate server like DemoProject-UI will run over (Tomcat) and DemoProject-Model will run 
on (Weblogic). Now you have 2 seprate project running on 2 different server.

If you want to keep both on same server then add maven dependency of second project to the first one and no need to go for web service.

Answer (score 1):

1. The best way is that you can create module and a create a final
   project as parent pom and you can able to deploy from main project.
   So Finally one main project will be build after building sub
   modules.

   ```
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
       <groupId>com</groupId>
       <artifactId>practice</artifactId>
       <version>0.0.1</version>
   </parent>
   <groupId>com.xplanr</groupId>
   <artifactId>SheelBatchClient</artifactId>
   <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
   <properties>
       <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>junit</groupId>
           <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
           <version>3.8.1</version>
           <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
           <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
           <version>2.22.2</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
           <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
           <version>2.6.5</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
           <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
           <version>2.6.5</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
           <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
           <version>1.3.8</version>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <description>Xplanr Batch Client</description>
   <name>xplanrBatchClient</name>

   <scm>
       <connection>scm:git:git//github.com/XplanrAnalyticsInc/XplanrMain.git</connection>
   </scm>

   <build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.2</version>
               <configuration>
                   <source>1.8</source>
                   <target>1.8</target>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>

           <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                       </goals>
                       <configuration>
                           <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/utility/XplanrBatchClient/lib</outputDirectory>
                       </configuration>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
           </plugin>

           <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.0.2</version>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <id>copy-resources</id>
                       <!-- here the phase you need -->
                       <phase>validate</phase>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                       </goals>
                       <configuration>
                           <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/utility/XplanrBatchClient</outputDirectory>
                           <resources>
                               <resource>
                                   <directory>src/main/utility/XplanrBatchClient</directory>
                                   <filtering>true</filtering>
                               </resource>
                           </resources>
                           <configuration>
                               <archive>
                                   <manifest>
                                       <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                   </manifest>
                               </archive>
                           </configuration>
                       </configuration>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
           </plugin>

           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
               <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>1.4</version>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <phase>validate</phase>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>create</goal>
                       </goals>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
               <configuration>
                   <format>{0,number}</format>
                   <items>
                       <item>buildNumber</item>
                   </items>
                   <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                   <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
                   <revisionOnScmFailure>unknownbuild</revisionOnScmFailure>
                   <!-- <shortRevisionLength>5</shortRevisionLength> -->
               </configuration>
           </plugin>

           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.3.1</version>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <phase>package</phase>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>jar</goal>
                       </goals>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
               <configuration>
                   <jarName>xplanrBatchClient</jarName>
                   <version>1.0.0</version>
                   <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/utility/XplanrBatchClient/lib</outputDirectory>
                   <archive>
                       <manifestEntries>
                           <implementation-version>${project.version}</implementation-version>
                           <implementation-build>${buildNumber}</implementation-build>
                       </manifestEntries>
                   </archive>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>

       </plugins>
   </build>
   <version>1.0.0</version>
   ```

2.**Then you have to create a pom for main project** 
There you have to mention as parent as you can see below

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>practice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
</parent>
<groupId>com.practice</groupId>
<artifactId>framework</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<name>DAG Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://www.practiceanalytics.com/</url>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>practice</id>
        <name>framework</name>
        <url>file://libs</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>cloudera</id>
      <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
      <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>

</repositories>
<dependencies>


</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-jar</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>client</classifier>
                        <finalName>udf-framework</finalName>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/udf/*</include>
                        </includes>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/udf/lib</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                <webresources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        <targetpath>WEB-INF/classes</targetpath>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </webresources>
                <warName>${project.war.name}</warName>
                <warSourceExcludes>**/*.class</warSourceExcludes> -->
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>framework</finalName>
</build>
<description>Web Project for Practice Code</description>
```